# Install Ubuntu into the hard drive but to chose to boot from USB

Tags: installation, 12.04, boot, usb

I have a Lenovo Z570 with Win7 HomePremium 64 bit installed. It already has 4 primary partitions, so used EaseUS to create another logical drive in it. 
Is there a way that I could install the OS into that logical drive but choose to boot from a USB as I couldn't install grub into the MBR of the disk (may be pre-installed Win7 has something to do with it).

So I would want to achieve something like 
1. Normally boot into Win7
2. Connect USB and choose the USB to boot into Ubuntu.

Please advice and help.

Answer (score 1):

Run a live cd/usb(the usb must be other than the one u have to install ubuntu on it) and select the advanced option during installation.Do select the usb as the drive to install Ubuntu and boot loader.The usb should be something above 5GB capacity.Reboot with the USB connected and see system boot from it.It should show a boot menu, from which you could choose windows or Ubuntu to start with.See [this page](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/help/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows) to see how to make USB from Windows.When you create Ubuntu usb by this way, you need to pin this usb whenever you boot your system.

Comment: Hi Beeju, Thanks for the reply. But it seems I would install Ubuntu itself to USB. Sorry if I wasn't precise in my question. I want to have the Ubuntu installed in the logical drive of the native hard disk of the computer. I only need the boot-ing from the USB.